# nginx: how to protect download links with individual passwords

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, download, webserver, password-protection

I created a vue JS app that creates brain tumor segmentations. Once the segmentation file is generated users receive a download link to it via email. My segmentations are generated from a python aiohttp backend, I plan to use long obscure URLs for the download links, however I still want to protect the downloads with passwords. Every generated download link should use its own password.

Classic webservers like Apache would solve this with a `.htaccess` file, but according to nginx docs this is a bad idea, even though one finds guides to do it anyway:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache-htaccess/

So if `.htaccess` is not the way to go, how do I configure nginx to handle this use case?

Ideally my python backend would serve the generated `.zip` archive plus a password file put them in a folder and then nginx would serve these requiring users to only type in a password and no username.

Comment: Do you have any backend database ? If yes, I would suggest saving a generated password hash for every file. Additionnally, each file could have a unique id used in obscure URLs and the user would simply have to enter the generated password in a simple form to download the file ?

Comment: I actively try to avoid having a backend db...data I do not have cannot be stolen :)

Comment: I understand, good point. I wonder if this guide would help : http://flsilva.com/blog/how-to-password-protect-file-directory-nginx/
It sure seems strange to use an Apache package, but it seems you can use Apache .htpasswd concept with nginx. Could be interesting.

Comment: Thanks, I found this guide too but nginx docs seem to have a strong stance against it:
"You can’t do this. You shouldn’t. If you need .htaccess, you’re probably doing it wrong."